# FragmentStatePagerAdapter's notifyDatasetChanged method does not updating the view in some Phones

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragmentstatepageradapter

I got some problem while working with fragmentStatePagerAdapter, I have 3 fragments in my view pager and on Restart of activity I want to update the view which is in the view pager. I have used recycler view in second fragment and It's basically a chatting app. I have handled most of the cases as per my requirement but while testing I got the problem in Moto G3 and Lenovo K3. When my app is in background, user receives a new message and user comes from shuffling between apps or by coming from notification then its not refreshing the view. Although, I have also introduced some sound when in-coming message comes up in chat. I can hear the sound in that case but not able to see any message. My message screen is blank in this case. Also, This issue is not with every phone.

I have used this method   `mViewPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();` for the update. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, the only solution worked for me was to reset the view pager adapter. (pager.removeAdapter / pager.setAdapter)